# Pyspark - Groupby and collect list over multiple columns and create multiple columns

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the below dataframe over which I am trying to group by and aggregate data.

```
Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
A        N1       P1
A        N2       P2
A        N3       P3
B        N1       P1
C        N1       P1
C        N2       P2
```

Required Output:

```
Column_1 Column_2 Column_3
A        N1,N2,N3 P1,P2,P3
B        N1       P1
C        N1,N2    P1,P2
```

I am able to do it over one column by creating a window using partition and groupby. 
Then I use collect list and group by over the window and aggregate to get a column. THis works for one column.

How to perform the same over 2 columns. Kindly help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [agg](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.agg) function of the [group by](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy) can take more than one aggreation function. You can add [collect_list](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe#pyspark.sql.functions.collect_list) twice:

```python
df.groupby('Column_1').agg(F.collect_list('Column_2'), F.collect_list('Column_3')).orderBy('Column_1').show()
```

prints

```
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+
|Column_1|collect_list(Column_2)|collect_list(Column_3)|
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+
|       A|          [N1, N2, N3]|          [P1, P2, P3]|
|       B|                  [N1]|                  [P1]|
|       C|              [N1, N2]|              [P1, P2]|
+--------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

For a simple grouping there is no need to use a [Window](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.Window).

Comment: WOrking as expected. Is there a link or an article which clearly states on what scenarios we have to use window? and where we can use groupby like above. Would be helpful to learn. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://knockdata.github.io/spark-window-function/) is helpful. As a  rule of thumb I would use windows when I expect the numbers of rows after the operation to stay the same and I would use a groupBy if I expect the number of rows in the result to be lower than in the original dataset.